# Wro4j : RubySassCss preprocessor is ignored

Tags: wro4j

I'm using wro4j 1.7.1 in a spring application. Recently I tried to add the RubySassCss preprocessor to the preprocessor I used but without any success.

The configuration I used :

```
# wro4j
debug=true
modelUpdatePeriod=0
gzipResources=false
disableCache=true
preProcessors=rubySassCss
# I tried also in post processing
#postProcessors=rubySassCss
managerFactoryClassName=com.workable.config.WroManager
```

It's not clear in the documentation which syntax I can use (scss or sass) so I have two files in a group :

```
<group name="test">
    <css>/sass/example.sass</css>
    <css>/sass/example.scss</css>
</group>
```

When I display this group on a page (localhost/wro/test.css, I just see the content of those files without any processing :

the sass file :

```
=border-radius($radius)
 -webkit-border-radius:$radius
 -moz-border-radius:$radius
 -ms-border-radius:$radius
 border-radius:$radius
```

the scss file :

```
.box
 +border-radius(10px)@mixin border-radius($radius){-webkit-border-radius:$radius;-moz-border-radius:$radius;-ms-border-radius:$radius;border-radius:$radius;}.box{@include border-radius(10px);}.box{-webkit-border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-ms-border-radius:10px;border-radius:10px;}
```

any idea ?

Comment: what exactly the com.workable.config.WroManager is doing? Could you replace it with ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory ? If it still doesn't work, enable debug log level to understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: Ok, it was our custom WroManager that were not up to date with the last version of Wro4j. Thanks a lot for your watchful eye :)

Comment: I'll post the above comment as an answer for visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your custom managerFactoryClassName is causing this problem.
Replace

```
managerFactoryClassName=com.workable.config.WroManager
```

with

```
managerFactoryClassName=ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory
```

If it still doesn't work, enable debug log level and check if there is something relevant there.